# What is a short, general term for automated browser testing?

Tags: automated-tests, terminology, browser-testing

I often want to refer, generally, to automated browser tests (like Selenium or PhantomJS).

The only terms I've heard describe it unambiguously are quite long, and make them unwieldy in conversation ("automated browser tests"), aren't specific enough ("automated tests" can mean unit tests), or are too specific about technology involved ("selenium tests"). Other terms aren't specific about the automated nature, like "end to end tests" (which perhaps could mean manual testing).

A phrase I've been using is "robot tests", which works well enough, but I've not heard this used anywhere.

Is there a better term?

Answer (score 2):

Full disclosure I use Selenium for my UI testing in .Net or Java.

**Automated browser testing**

It depends who I'm talking to:

- [Coded UI tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/use-ui-automation-to-test-your-code) - MS version of UI testing which has been re branded to Automated UI tests
- [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) tests - Agnostic version of UI testing
- UI tests - this could mean something more like [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/) tests. It's not specific enough when talking to manual testers and non technical Project Managers.

**Other tests**

- [Subcurtaneous tests](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/SubcutaneousTest.html): one layer below the UI tests (API/Service layer)
- [Approval tests](https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.Net) : Using human intelligence to verify objects
- [Pragmatic test](http://wirfs-brock.com/blog/2011/09/23/what-is-pragmatic-testing-all-about/): Pragmatic use of the different types of testing (acceptance tests, smoke tests, integration, performance and load tests support incremental development)
- [Test Pyramid](https://www.martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html) : UI Tests, Service tests, Unit Tests. I would use these around developers.
- [VCR Tests](https://github.com/vcr/vcr): replay the objects send to the server such as API requests.

I haven't heard of Robot tests, I have seen a "botcave" in the Selenium slack but that refers to events on GitHub that then get posted on slack. I find robot tests particularly confusing because I'm not sure whether you are referring to actual tests carried out on physical robots, robots that are carrying out tests, daemons that are running in the background or UI tests. It could be used with stakeholders so I'll have to try it out!

**TL;DR**

- Use UI tests with developers.
- Use Automated browser/UI tests with Stakeholders.
- [End to End Tests](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/what-is-end-to-end-testing/) if the tests are going through all the layers UI -> Persistent storage/DB and you need to convey that to the person writing them.

**Edit**

### Language changes over time

Here are some interesting trends kindly provided by Google:

- [end to end](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=end%20to%20end&geo=US) has seen a gradual decrease.
- [google testing blogs 2015](https://testing.googleblog.com/2015/04/just-say-no-to-more-end-to-end-tests.html) and
- [testing blog 2016](https://testing.googleblog.com/2016/09/testing-on-toilet-what-makes-good-end.html).
- [automated browser testing](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=automated%20browser%20testing&geo=US)
- [test automation](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=%2Fm%2F044stn)
- [selenium automation testing](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=selenium%20automation%20testing)
- [UI testing](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=ui%20testing)
- [automated testing](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=automated%20testing)
- [acceptance testing](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=%2Fm%2F014mm)
- [black box](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=%2Fm%2F01f12)
- [functional testing](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=%2Fm%2F0fzlgj)
- [coded ui testing](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=Coded%20UI%20testing) is a term that's no longer used
- [selenium tests](https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?geo=US&q=selenium%20tests) is a term that has a downward trend

[Bing has a similar service](https://www.bing.com/toolbox/keywords)

So my interpretation of the data at a very brief glance is some of these terms have a regional slant (geolocation = US) and you would need to input your location to determine which [dialect](https://www.theatlantic.com/international/archive/2016/01/difference-between-language-dialect/424704/) to speak.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer! The problem I have with the these terms ("UI testing", "End to end testing"), even with developers, is it doesn't exclude _manual_ UI testing.

Comment: I forgot to mention audio chat bots and text chat bots so UI could be something other than a web page. found a brilliant article mentioned in the selenium slack channel [watirtight testing](http://watirtight.com/2016/12/19/stop-saying-that.html)